# permutation of a group of $2a$ numbers: $\{1,1,2,2,3,3,.....,a-1,a-1,a,a\}$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

An integer $a$ is 'good', when there exists a permutation of a group of $2a$ numbers: $\{1,1,2,2,3,3,.....,a-1,a-1,a,a\}$ such that between two numbers $k=1,2,..a$, there are exactly $k$ numbers. Prove that the integer $a$ is 'good' only when $a(a+1)$ is divisible by 4

I found that 'good' number $a$ must be $4k$ or $4k+3$. We have to prove that $a=4k+1, 4k+2$ is not 'good' and $a=4k, 4k+3$ is 'good'

Comment: Really sorry, that was my misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem statement is

> Prove that the integer $a$ is 'good' only when $a(a+1)$ is divisible by 4.

You say that you have

> found that 'good' number $a$ must be $4k$ or $4k+3$.

That's all you need, you're done. From there you go on to say

> We have to prove that $a=4k+1,4k+2$ is not 'good'

That's the same thing as 'good' number $a$ must be $4k$ or $4k+3$. So you've already done that. Finally, you say

> and $a=4k,4k+3$ is 'good'

No, that's not something you're asked to do. We are not asked to show that all of $3,4,7,8,11,12,\ldots$ are good. Just that all good numbers are in that sequence.